# Cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Tags: oracle, python-2.7, cx-oracle

Getting this :
Cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00984: column not allowed here ERROR while trying to insert data in Oracle Spatial DB via Python.

Reading data from XLS.Below is the code snippet of iterative reading and loading values :

```
for r in range (2,high_row ):
 long  = sheet_ranges['A'+str(r)].value
 lat = sheet_ranges['B'+str(r)].value
 state  = sheet_ranges['C'+str(r)].value
 cty = sheet_ranges['D'+str(r)].value
 print lat
 print long
 print state
 print cty
 cur.execute('INSERT INTO NONMODEL_CAT_HAZARD (LONGITUDE,LATITUDE,STATE,COUNTRY) VALUES ('+str(long)+','+str(lat)+','+str(state)+','+str(cty)+')')      
 cxn.commit()
```

Output :

501
   0
   33.64
   -117.84
   CA
   US

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "NMCatHazardLoadxls.py", line 32, in 
   cur.execute('INSERT INTO NONMODEL_CAT_HAZARD (LONGITUDE,LATITUDE,STATE,COUNTRY) VALUES
 ('+str(long)+','+str(lat)+','+str(state)+','+str(cty)+')')
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Please assist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put all string values in single quotes (don't know which ones are strings, which numbers, so I did make all in single quotes):

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO NONMODEL_CAT_HAZARD (LONGITUDE,LATITUDE,STATE,COUNTRY) VALUES (\''+str(long)+'\',\''+str(lat)+'\',\''+str(state)+'\',\''+str(cty)+'\')')
```

Comment: File "NMCatHazardLoadxls.py", line 32, in <module>
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO NONMODEL_CAT_HAZARD (LONGITUDE,LATITUDE,STATE,COUNTRY) VALUES
 (\''+str(long)+'\',\''+str(lat)+'\',\''+str(state)+'\',\''+str(cty)+'\')\'')
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

Comment: Gave me the above error.Also , i'm type casting value to string : str() , so what is the need of single quotes for string values ?

Comment: Added one single quote to much. Edited answer.
Single quotes are needed by Oracle syntax.